# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal at line 1 column 21403 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My JSON data is too long contains many objects. When I parse the data I get error:

`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal at line 1 column 21403 of the JSON data
http://localhost/c2c/content/scripts/jqueryEngine/jquery.js line 2 > eval
Line 10`.

Here its written 21403 column in firebug. How which object's property lies in column 21403 so that I can make correction.

Comment: something corrupted your json string. you'll have to grab it and look to see what it is.

Comment: Copy the JSON response into a text editor. and go to column 21403 to find the bad character.

Comment: which text editor show column number. I use netbeans. Is it possible from netbeans.